# Constructing PDA to accept language $L=\{a^i b^j c^k \mid k\geq \min(i,j)\}$

Tags: pushdown-automata

How can I construct a PDA which accepts the language   $\{a^i b^j c^k \mid k\geq \min(i,j)\}$

I think about different solutions such as building a stack with two-state. one state is for $i < j$ and another is for $i > j$, But I think it doesn't work.

also, The idea of poping and pushing a and b is not good. I tried it. Can Someone give me a little hint?

Comment: Your basic idea looks like a good starting point. Try to think of how to implement the decision whether $i<j$ or vice versa, and how you could split the cases up.

Comment: @nirshahar I think about this. but the idea is related to pushing a and poping b, and when I do this I lost my data for c and I can't decide on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to differentiate between $i<j$ and $i >j$ is good.

To help you building the PDA, note that $L = \{a^ib^jc^k | k \geq i\} \cup \{a^ib^jc^k|k\geq j\}$.

I hope that hint is enough.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point.